# Gatling https proxy

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I use gatling to do the performance test. The httpProxy like this:

`http.proxy(Proxy(${proxyHost}, 9000)).baseUrl("https://").headers(headers)`

If the ${proxyHost} can be access with http, then it's ok.
But if the ${proxyHost} should be access with https, then it doesn't work, the error is:
`i.n.h.p.ProxyConnectException: http, none, ...`

I wander if Gatling doesn't support https proxy?

I try to set environment variable in the server which execute gatling test cases like this:

`export https_proxy = https://${proxyHost}:9000`

But it seems don't work, the request didn't go through the proxy.

Could someone give me some help?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP proxy host is a static field. You can’t use Gatling Expression Language there.

Comment: It's not a gatling expression, actually it's a host name, i didn't write it clearly. I think Gatling will make a request like `curl https://www.google.com --proxy http://xxx:9000`, but what i want is `curl https://www.google.com --proxy https://xxx:9000`, because my proxy need https access.